# Can we pass a JavaScript variable to a Python file?

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet

I am developing a simple webpage GUI for my satellite images for a machine learning project. All the files are on my local machine and I intend to host the website locally as well. I have used plain Javascript and a third party library, Leaflet to display the image(kind of like a map).

The map displayed is basically a tiled version of image. I need to pass on the path of the tile (which I am currently storing in a js variable) to a python file which will use it to perform feature extraction of that particular tile.

Initially, I attempted to write it into a text file that the python program would read, but that displays a prompt everytime for downloading the file. Most of the other solutions involved FS module of NodeJS.

I am sorry if it is a very simple question I am a beginner and could not find any answer on the above (almost every answer uses some flavor of js)

Comment: Send an AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. You need some port/socket open with a python script listening. You could try flask or django if you want to send content back and have a framework for a site, or just use anything that listens on a socket. It's far too broad, though, to answer properly

Comment: @roganjosh perhaps being a noob I may be taking the wrong approach. I will try flask, as suggested by you and another comment since it seems to best fit my use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using Flask micro web-framework ? It is the easiest way of integrating ML projects with web.

Check these videos if it helps

[Deploying deep learning using flask for an image recogntion project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSEmUmkfb8Q&t=154s)

[Deploy ML model using flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbCWoMf80PY&t=1s)

Comment: I am surprised I did not know of flask until today. It fits my case requirements. I will check out the links as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need send data to python send JSON

Put it in your js and AJAX will be send to python script:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/my_data",
        data: "data=Hello",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(response).msg);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(response).msg);
            alert("Ajax error!");
        }
});
```

And then python will get request and send response:

```py
@app.route('/my_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ajax_data():
    message = request.form['data']
    print(message)
    try:
        return json.dumps({'msg': "Message was successfully sent!"})
    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'msg': "Message send error : " + e.message})
```